# In a table with row headers and column headers, given a column header text and a cell text, how can I select a cell (td)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given this table:

```
<table border>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>B</th>
            <td id="i0j0">sa</td>
            <td id="i0j1">sa</td>
            <td id="i0j2">sb</td>
            <td id="i0j3">sa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>C</th>
            <td id="i1j0">sb</td>
            <td id="i1j1">sb</td>
            <td id="i1j2">sb</td>
            <td id="i1j3">sb</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>D</th>
            <td id="i2j0">sc</td>
            <td  id="i2j1">sc</td>
            <td id="i2j2">sc</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If the desired pair is column header "B" and cell "sa", the td with id `i0j1` should be returned. If the pair is column header "B" and cell "sb", element with id `i1j1` should be returned.

I was having a problem posing this question before, it wasn't quite clear. Let me know if you need more information. A JSBin with the representation of it is found here:  http://jsbin.com/amowUBA/7/edit

Comment: You will have to lop through the elements and look at their (text) content until you find what you want.

Comment: Hi @CBroe! I was hoping to have a selector like `$('th:contains("B")').add('td:contains("sa")')`, but that is rather returning the one matching the row header and not the column `th`.

Comment: Try using `find` after selecting the TH element to find a matching TD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this scenario:

```
  _parameter = 'B';
  _state = 'sa';  

  // columns are in the first row
  var column = $('tr:eq(0) > th:contains("'+_parameter+'")');
  var cell = $('td:nth-child('+parseInt(column.index()+1)+'):contains("'+_state+'")');
```

To see it implemented, check this: http://jsbin.com/amowUBA/9/edit